# LINQ select returning NULL when creating a new object

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using LINQ to return a list of results in a new object.

The end result should effectively be:

```
var test = context.Playarea
            .Include(x => x.Cats)
            .Where(x => x.Cats.Any())
            .SelectMany(x => x.Cats.Select(y => new MyClass(x.Id, y.Name)));
```

I have tested the below and it neatly returns a list of names.

```
var test = context.Playarea
            .Include(x => x.Cats)
            .Where(x => x.Cats.Any())
            .SelectMany(x => x.Cats.Select(y => y.Name));
```

If I try and convert it to a very simple object however I get a NULL exception?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
     }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


var test = context.Playarea
            .Include(x => x.Cats)
            .Where(x => x.Cats.Any())
            .SelectMany(x => x.Cats.Select(y => new MyClass(y.Name)));
```

There is nothing that can be NULL so I don't understand how it is getting this?

```
GetEnumerator(): Exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' was thrown
```

I am using the same class elsewhere, the only difference here is the use of SelectMany().

Anonymous objects also work fine:

```
var test = context.Playarea
                .Include(x => x.Cats)
                .Where(x => x.Cats.Any())
                .SelectMany(x => x.Cats.Select(y => new { Id = x.Id, Name = y.Name } ));
```

Comment: `SelectMany` will never return `null`, but how are you observing the results? THe debugger is notoriously bad at showing the exact results due to deferred execution.

Comment: I'm using breakpoints in JetBrains Rider. My code returns a valid list of strings, but it can't cope with creating a new MyClass.

Comment: I would create an actual collection using `ToList()` to view the results. That will be more definitive than the debugger.

Comment: I tried using ToList() on my test and it does create a List of strings. If I do it when trying to create a class I just get a 500 error.

Comment: Must be something in one of the entity classes of which we see no code. Side note: you can remove the `Include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions stack trace shows that the exception originates from EF Core infrastructure

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.MemberAccessShiftingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression node)
```

which clearly indicates EF Core bug.

Note that projection using constructors is supported only client-side, i.e. only when it is the final query operation, so most likely the bug is caused by a missing case in the EF Core 3.x query processing pipeline.

Anyway, you haven't asked a concrete question, just showed an issue and symptoms, so you should really go and report it at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues.

If you are looking for workaround, I can suggest the following two.

If you need just `y`, you can move the `Select` *after* `SelectMany`, e.g.

```
.SelectMany(x => x.Cats).Select(y => new MyClass(y.Name));
```

If you need both `x` and `y`, or in general, you could replace the `Select` with the `SelectMany` overload with result selector, e.g.

```
.SelectMany(x => x.Cats, (x, y) => new MyClass(x.Id, y.Name))
```